# Construction of a $2$-form

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a Riemann surface and $\mathcal{E}^2(\mathcal{X})$ the $\mathbb{C}$-Vector space of all differentiable $2$-forms on $\mathcal{X}$.

I want to construct a $2$-form $ \omega  \in \mathcal{E}^2(\mathcal{X})$ on $\mathcal{X}$ without zeroes.

Comment: @jdc: There is no holomorphic 2-form on a complex 1-manifold other than $0$. Nor did the OP specify a compact Riemann surface of genus $g>1$.

Comment: Ted, these are good points. I have deleted my useless comment.

Answer (score 1):

You just want the standard construction of a [volume form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form) on any orientable differentiable manifold. There's nothing going on here with the complex manifold structure.

**EDIT**: Here's an outline for you to fill in.

1. Cover $X$ with *compatibly oriented* charts $x_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to\Bbb C$.
2. Let $\phi_i$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_\alpha\}$, with $\operatorname{supp}(\phi_i)\subset U_{\alpha(i)}$.
3. Consider the $2$-form $\omega = \displaystyle\sum_i \phi_i\, x_{\alpha(i)}^*(dx^1\wedge dx^2)$.
4. Prove that this $\omega$ is well-defined and, moreover, nowhere $0$ because the charts are compatibly oriented.

Comment: See my edit. This ought to be enough for you to complete the task.

Comment: Sounds like you need to study differential forms more. If you prefer, we can rewrite that as $dx^1_{\alpha(i)}\wedge dx^2_{\alpha(i)}$. Orientation has nothing to do with the partition of unity. But it does tell you that on overlaps, the signs of $dx^1_{\alpha(i)}\wedge dx^2_{\alpha(i)}(v,w)$ and $dx^1_{\alpha(j)}\wedge dx^2_{\alpha(j)}(v,w)$ must agree for any tangent vectors $v,w\in T_pX$.